# installing java on compute engine instance without external ip address

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vpn

I am having some issues while trying to install java : "sudo apt install default-jre" on a VM instance :
[image]

I realized that my VM has no external ip address as my company wont allow it.
I can ping the localhost on the VM but not [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) fro example so i figured the lack of external IP was the issue.
Is there another way that i can install java on this VM?
I just have a basic java code (not an app) that i want to try by running "java -jar myjarname.jar".

Any idea would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to be able to download from the Internet, set up a NAT Gateway.

[Cloud NAT overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)

Another option is to set up a VPN to your corporate network which provides a route to the Internet.

Otherwise, you will need to upload files to your VM and install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not upload the `*.deb` package and then install it?

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files